# How do I create a rosserial_arduino package under Cmake with Groovy?

Tags: arduino, rosserial, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Working with rosserial_arduino within the Arduino IDE is tedious and I would like to start using CMake to automate builds of my package.  Unfortunately, the following tutorial seems woefully out of date for Groovy:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/CMake

The tutorial uses *roscreate-pkg*, but the cmake scripts were [removed from rosserial_arduino a few months back](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/commit/60e534e9ea7bddee42d52ffc12f473bb25f1d716) by Fergs.  I guess the reason why is explained [here](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/issues/50).

Can anyone provide hints how to get rosserial_arduino based projects working with cmake under Arduino?  A pointer to an existing package for Groovy that I could copy under github or something would be terrific.

Thanks,

Mike Thompson

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67810/how-do-i-create-a-rosserial_arduino-package-under-cmake-with-groovy?/) by [mpthompson](https://answers.ros.org/users/3684/mpthompson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2013-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The old Cmake scripts are still in the repository history. Unfortunately, they were out of date and so they were removed as I didn't have time to update them. If someone updates them and opens a pull request to merge them back in, in an updated form, I'm sure the rosserial team would merge that request.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mpthompson](https://answers.ros.org/users/3684/mpthompson/) on 2013-07-20**:
OK thanks for the info.  I'm looking at the ROS Arduino Bridge as well so I may pursue that route.